# How can I decrease the length of my field Label in Odoo V13

Tags: python, odoo

Eg:
Here's my XML view code:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="user_form" >
   <field name="name">User Form</field>
   <field name="model">user</field>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
       <group>
           <field name="name"/>
           <field name="password"/>
           <field name="Active"/>
           <field name="power_of_using_the_complete_session"/>
       </group>
       <notebook>
```

In the UI i see the `power of using the complete session` field coming in two lines. How can we extend it to the single line in XML view?

I tried using colspan but it didnt seems to be working.

Comment: If you want to do this in this form only, use label tag with special class I think you can use style also i'm not sure. Odoo defines a max width for label tag you can change this in your scss but this will effect all forms. I hope you know how to add custom scss and you got the idea good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi let me try to help.

In xml you can use **`width`** attribute in field to increase fields' width.

**For Example:**

```
<field name="your_field_name" width="130"/>
```

Secondly you can use some html tags and attributes to resolve this.

**For Example:**

```
<div class="row">
    <label string="Field String" for="field_id" class="col-lg-5 o_light_label"/>
    <field name="you_field_name" id="field_id" class="oe_inline"/>             
</div>
```

Here you're replacing field string your custom label and defining its length by using **`col-lg-5`**

Comment: It seems to be good. I want bold label instead of light and i need vertical pipe for eg., ```fieldName   |    Value```